# Unable to use OverthereConnection through commandline

Tags: java, maven, truezip

I have enabled overthereconnection's through Spring IDE, but when I try running my maven-built application via commandline, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: jar (Unknown file system scheme! May be the class path doesn't contain the respective driver module or it isn't set up correctly?)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsAbstractCompositeDriver.newController(FsAbstractCompositeDriver.java:33)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsDefaultManager.getController0(FsDefaultManager.java:95)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsDefaultManager.getController(FsDefaultManager.java:78)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.file.TFile.getController(TFile.java:1497)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.file.TFile.parse(TFile.java:687)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.file.TFile.<init>(TFile.java:659)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.file.TFile.<init>(TFile.java:601)
        at nl.javadude.scannit.reader.TFiles.tFile(TFiles.java:23)
        at nl.javadude.scannit.reader.ArchiveEntrySupplier.withArchiveEntries(ArchiveEntrySupplier.java:23)
        at nl.javadude.scannit.Worker.scanFiles(Worker.java:59)
        at nl.javadude.scannit.Worker.scanURI(Worker.java:53)
        at nl.javadude.scannit.Worker.scan(Worker.java:46)
        at nl.javadude.scannit.Scannit.<init>(Scannit.java:41)
        at com.xebialabs.overthere.Overthere.boot(Overthere.java:74)
        at com.xebialabs.overthere.Overthere.<clinit>(Overthere.java:69)
        at com.emc.ondemand.agent.core.discovery.AnalyzeSelf.constructODEnvironmentForSingleHost(AnalyzeSelf.java:172)
        at com.emc.ondemand.agent.core.discovery.DiscoverEnvironment.discoverEnvironment(DiscoverEnvironment.java:85)
        at com.emc.ondemand.agent.core.discovery.DiscoverEnvironment.main(DiscoverEnvironment.java:48)
```

My code call looks like:

```
    // establish winrm connection to target host
    ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions(); 
    options.set(ADDRESS, myHost.getIP()); 
    options.set(USERNAME, user); 
    options.set(PASSWORD, pass); 
    options.set(OPERATING_SYSTEM, WINDOWS); 
    options.set(CONNECTION_TYPE, WINRM_NATIVE); // was not able to get WINRM_INTERNAL to work with processes
    connection = Overthere.getConnection("cifs", options);
```

This is the only dependency I have:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xebialabs.overthere</groupId>
        <artifactId>overthere</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

It does pull in the correct Truezip classes so I'm at a loss as to what it means exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your dependency is an uber-JAR? Please check if there is a file named `META-INF/services/de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.spi.FsDriverService` on the class path. Among others, it needs to contain the following entry:

```
de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.archive.zip.ZipDriverService
```

If that's not the case, then please contact the creator of the `overthere` artifact and tell them that they appear to have incorrectly assembled their artifact from the TrueZIP dependencies.

In all cases, you should be able to fix this problem by adding another dependency to your class path:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>de.schlichtherle.truezip</groupId>
  <artifactId>truezip-driver-zip</artifactId>
  <version>7.7.9</version>
</dependency>
```